# "open" from the command line just hangs using iTerm2

Tags: command-line

The

```
open -a <AppName.app>
```

is not working on one of my Yosemite based macbooks. The other one - also with Yosemite - works fine.

```
open -a TextEdit.app ~/out

(just hangs )
```

I have also tried other apps - to make sure the problem were not specifically with TextEdit. Nothing works.  Also I *am* able to use Finder to open apps with TextEdit.

AFA the app's attempted:  let us look at a simple built-in one:

```
 $open -a TextEdit.app ~/out
```

Note that "open" has not been disturbed in any way: it is the one shipped with the MacBook

```
12:23:07/Applications $which open
/usr/bin/open

ls -lrta $(which open)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  92912 Sep 12  2014 /usr/bin/open
```

Comment: On the system having a problem, from Terminal, execute the following command, as is, and reports if TextEdit opens normally to a blank document or still hangs. `open -a TextEdit`

Comment: yes that hangs on iTerm2. I had realize a few minutes earlier that the issue appears to be with  iTerm2 (vs Terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue were rather with `iTerm2`.   I tried the same commands on Terminal and it worked fine.  I do need some of the features of iTerm and am investigating which version(s) actually work. The one I am using (and does *not* work) is the one on the Download link.  So far I am having better luck with their iTerm 3.0 Alpha version.